# Cannot get multiline text using mysql_fetch_array

Tags: php, mysql

I can't get TEXT value as multiline:

PHP:

```
$mysql_conn = mysql_connect("host", "username", "password");
mysql_select_db("database", $mysql_conn);
$my_query = mysql_query("SELECT a, b FROM c WHERE a='example'", $mysql_conn);
$mysql_array = mysql_fetch_array($my_query);
```

HTML & PHP:

```
<p><?php echo $mysql_array["b"]; ?></p>
```

MySQL Table Structure `c`:

```
a = VARCHAR (100) ...
b = TEXT ...
```

Table `c` (only contains 1 row):

Value of `a` (1st row):
MyText

Value of `b` (1st row):
My 1st line
My 2nd line
My 3rd line
My 4th line

`b` is TEXT (no varchar), so `b` supports multiline.

When I retrieve `b`, multiline is automatically converted in space:

My output of `$mysql_array["b"]`:

```
`My 1st line My 2nd line My 3rd line My 4th line`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should solve this with:

```
echo nl2br($result[msg]);
```

The browser does not recognize `\r\n` as new-lines so you have to you convert them to `<br>`.

[nl2br function](http://php.net/nl2br)

Answer (score 0):

Use `nl2br` to change the newlines in the data into HTML `<br>` tags.

```
<p><?php echo nl2br($mysql_array["b"]); ?></p>
```

Or you could use a `<pre>` element to keep all the original formatting.

```
<p><pre><?php echo $mysql_array["b"]; ?></pre></p>
```